# Is there a name for this type of polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I'm developing theory to solve a type of polynomial which I call the 'non-standard polynomial'. I'd like to know if this is something which is already known but I'm unsure how to search for it.

Consider two $N$ dimensional vectors

$\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}\in \mathbb{C}^N$ where elements of $\mathbf{r}$ are not necessarily integer values

then the 'polynomial', which is a function of $\theta$ is constructed as

$P(\theta) = \alpha_1^{r_1\theta} + \alpha_2^{r_2\theta}+\dots+\alpha_N^{r_N\theta}$

In my case $|\alpha_n| = 1$ for $n=1,\dots,N$.

Is anyone aware of theory around such a 'polynomial'? If so, what should I search for?

Comment: Linear combinations of powers can be called *fractional polynomials*. I don't know of a special name when all coefficients are unit.

Comment: Up to an overall offset of all the $r$, the polynomial you have is a [Dirichlet polynomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

This might be called a *multivariate fractional polynomial*, but I doubt that there is a theory about that, for two reasons:

1. complex powers like $\alpha^r$ where $r$ is a real number have little meaning.
2. as the $\alpha_k$ and $r_k$ are unrelated and each appears once only, you in fact have a sum of complex numbers $b_k:=\alpha_k^{r_k}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: because of the argument indeterminacy, this has little meaning.